# Regex(PHP) of finding all concurrences beginning with a set string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am currently trying to make a game of ghost and this is my php file that uses regex to update a string in my html file that lists all letters that could possibly form a word following the string. (like for liche, it would echo n for possible letters) In addition, I have a text file with all words in the english dictionary that I am pulling data from for preg_match_all(). However, my code keeps returning nothing and I am not sure why.

The for loop is specific to the game ghost. The rules of the game are for each player to say a letter with the purpose of forming a word. However, whoever says the last letter that forms the word wins. For example, if person 1 says Z, person 2 says E, p1 says B, p2 says R, then p1 will lose because the only possible letter left is A which would form a complete word. However, the rule that made me create this for loop was to exclude all words that were under 3 words in length (a, an the, cat, etc.)

If I were to have input the string loa (retrieved by REQUEST), then all words in the wordsEn.txt file that started with loa would be added to an array. From there, the next letter after loa would be added to a string s1 (no repeated letters though; n should not be repeated twice for loan and loans). Lasty, this would echo s1 which would be later used in html.

```
<?php 
$contents=file_get_contents('wordsEn.txt');
    $a=$_REQUEST['word'];//gets current combo from the url
    $pattern='/^'+$a+'.*/';
    $length=strlen($a);
    $letters='';
    if(preg_match_all($pattern,$contents,$matches)){
        for($n=0; $n<count($matches); $n++){
            if($length>3 and $matches[$n]==$a){// if it is a word with length over 3
                $n=$length+4;
                $letters='';//no matches
            }
            else{
                $next=$matches[$n]+'';
                $temp=substr($next, $length-1, $length); //get the next letter
                if(strpos($letters, $temp)==FALSE){
                    $temp=substr($next, $length-1, $length);
                    $letters+=$temp;
                }
            }
        }
        echo($letters);
    }
```

?>

Comment: Welcome to SO! I hope you'll find the site useful. In my experience, learning to use the site also helped me to grow personally as a developer. This is a great start to asking a good question. You have an idea about what you want to achieve and it makes sense intuitively, however it is missing an example of what you've tried together with the output you observed and the desired output. Please consider adding these such that other users can test your code and provide you with code in return that's useful for you.

Comment: Thanks! I've added more specifics on the project I am working on and hope this will make it more clear to others.

Comment: There are mistakes in your code, Strings concatenation is done via `.` not `+`; `$matches` is multi-dimensional so `$matches[n]` is an array, not a string; why are you doing `$n=$length+4;`? I'm pretty sure that `$next=$matches[$n]+'';` doesn't do what you think........

Answer (score 1):

you can try this regex

```
(pa)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

**here is a demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/pUeIvw/1

in php you can implement like this

DEMO:http://phpio.net/s/d37

Comment: Could you please look at my new question? I made it more specific and provided more code.

Comment: I have a variable $a that I want to use as the string (I am using a variable since it is always changing) that starts a word.

Comment: have look at this cod http://phpio.net/s/d49 then tell me what you want

Comment: If given a string $a and a document full of words, what regex would you put into preg_match_all(pattern, content, array) in order to store all words that start with string a (doesn't matter what comes after) into the array? (I hope this made more sense)

Comment: use $arr= array();   array_push($arr, $a);

Comment: i'm saying use array_push() to store all the words

Comment: How would you do this since all the words are stored in a separate text file?

Comment: man i did not understood your question but have a look at this created for you only http://phpio.net/s/d4d

Answer (score 1):

It's just as simple as:

```
^pa.*
```

Where:

```
^    : is an anchor that means begining of string
pa   : literally letter "p" followed by letter "a"
.*   : any character (.) present 0 or more times (*)
```

**Edit according to question reformulation:**

The pattern you're loking for is:

```
$pattern = "/^$a.*/";
```

or, more restrictive:

```
$pattern = "/^$a\w*/";
```

---

> I don't understand the purpose of the for loop, please, explain what you want to do and add in your question some sample input strings an expected result.

Comment: The for loop is specific to the game ghost. The rules of the game are for each player to say a letter with the purpose of forming a word. However, whoever says the last letter that forms the word wins. For example, if person 1 says Z, person 2 says E, p1 says B, p2 says R, then p1 will lose because the only possible letter left is A which would form a complete word. However, the rule that made me create this for loop was to exclude all words that were under 3 words in length (a, an the, cat, etc.)

Comment: If I were to have input the string loa (retrieved by REQUEST), then all words in the wordsEn.txt file that started with loa would be added to an array. From there, the next letter after loa would be added to a string s1 (no repeated letters though; n should not be repeated twice for loan and loans). Lasty, this would echo s1 which would be later used in html.

Comment: @mlin: I don't understand why you are looping from `0` to `strlen($a)` and use this indice for the array `$matches` that makes no sense

Comment: @mlin: Please, edit your question instead of giving info in the comment.

Comment: that was a mistake on my part in naming the variables, I meant for the for loop to go through the length of the matches array.